# rails Netflix fast_jsonapi to pick serializer automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api, fastjsonapi

I using [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) for apis with [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) and

What I see that I have to always provide serializer name like

```
CompanySerializer.new(Company.all).serializable_hash
```

wondering if it can auto pick serialzier name depending upon resource name or object type like it used to do with active mode serializer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why you'll have to explicitly mention Serializer class every time.

1. You can have multiple Serializers for the same object/model.
   You may have to define multiple serializers when you need to pass different data for different requests.
2. Usually, we have to deal with multiple API versions (like v1, v2, v3) in such case you must have multiple serializers for the same model/object for the sack of compatibility of all API versions.

Comment: getting your point, but what if I have one serialzer, I have to provide serializer name everytime? auto thing not possible

Comment: I believe `fast_jsonapi` does not have this configuration.